# How to construct the rejection region for a one-tailed Likelihood-ratio test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, one-tailed-test

Suppose we have a likelihood-ratio test statistic for some parameter $\theta$, given by:

$$\lambda_{\text{LR}} = -2 \left\{\ell(\theta_0) - \ell(\hat{\theta}) \right\} $$

where $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE for $\theta$. Under the null hypothesis $\lambda_{\text{LR}}$ asymptotically follows a $\chi_1^2$ distribution, so a rejection region at level $\alpha$ for the two-tailed test

$$
\begin{cases}
  H_0: \theta = \theta_0 \\
  H_1: \theta \neq \theta_0
\end{cases}
$$

is $\lambda_{\text{LR}} > \chi_{1, 1-\alpha}^2$.

But what if we have **a one-tailed test**:

$$
\begin{cases}
  H_0: \theta \leq \theta_0 \\
  H_1: \theta > \theta_0
\end{cases}
$$

**What would be the rejection region in this case, assuming that $\lambda_{\text{LR}}$ follows a chi-squared distribution under the null?**